# populate form using selenium RC with unique ID's

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to populate a form using Selenium RC.  The form fields have unique IDs i.e. I cannot specify them in my RC code.  I could use the following with webdriver:

```
driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
```

Is there something similar I could look into for selenium RC or should I be considering RC backed by webdriver?  thanks

Comment: From what I can tell RC is on the way out, so if it's new development I'd use WebDriver.

Comment: that's what I thought but I have some old code that I'm thinking of extending instead of rewriting/migrating - I will migrate if there are no other options as of right now.  thank you for your feedback - appreciated

Comment: I'm trying to see where xpathcount would help me get this resolved.  will keep everyone posted - please feel free to suggest if that's the correct route

Comment: You're not using Selenium RC, you're using WebDriver.  `driver.findElements()` is part of the WebDriver API.

Comment: yes I know - I mentioned that I am using driver.findElements with webdriver and I need to use something similar with RC.